# Logger/ data store recommendation

Tags: database, search, logging, queue, storage

I am looking for a recommendation for the following scenario: we have a service that consists of, on a high level, a front-end web app serving API and web UI requests (the latter are less important) -- decomposing, putting them as tasks in queue for processing, and a number of worker services consuming the tasks from the queue and processing them. The API clients would poll for results asynchronously.

We need to be able to log pieces of information along the way (starting from the originating request, through intermediate outputs, to final results) so that they can be accessed later if needed (mostly to troubleshoot what went wrong for a given request).

Ultimately, what we need is:

- To be used as a secure storage for information related to logging and short term auditing,
- Low overhead insertion:

  - (Low) constant time insertion, either truly non-blocking or effectively non-blocking (guaranteed quick),
  - Very frequent insertion – think multiple inserts per one CF API call,
- Retrieval used significantly less frequently, can be slow-ish,
- Items need to be retrievable at least by ID, but...
- Payloads are effectively text or binary

  - Full text search capability would be a plus,
  - Understanding the structure of the text, e.g. being able to query JSON 
    elements is a mild nice-to-have,
- Data retention policies either built in or easy to implement.

"Secure" means we're processing personal information in several countries, usual regulations/ standards apply.

This can be software (open source, usable in commercial environment) that we'd host ourselves or an Amazon AWS service.

Answer (score 0):

checkout, as a base for your app,  sherlock on Sourceforge.net , it's an opensource a Log4J implementation, you could modify as you like,  ie- containerize the  headless tomcat server , it's a "Chain of Custody" "C2" compliant Rsyslog replacement server collector of syslog and syslogrelay data, which first stores the logs as flat files per source, then post processes and dumps the log data into a mysql db, thereafter there is an older  web client with some regex support to search/filter data so you can get at the log data for forensics..

The guys that put this together with me came from Platespin (later sold to Novell) , actually the team that built this code successfully sold a dervitative work for decent cash right at the time they built it, and then went on to work for Tibco(later Mulesoft) and RIM(Blackberry, and now BMO)... so its solid code

here is the link...

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sherlock/

r2

Comment: you can easily modify to suit your log generating sources, without much change required on the backend, then wire up/modify the post-processing part to suit your db and dashboard targets,.. I hope this helps..